# Reference current branch and origin/<current> in git alias

Tags: git, alias

As an example assume you want to write a git alias, which shows the difference between the current branch and its `origin` partner.

In the specific case of master it would look like the following:

```
[alias]
    top = log --oneline --graph --decorate master ^origin/master
```

How to replace `master`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your git version is not ridiculously old, the string `@{u}` means "upstream", i.e., whatever origin/foo the current branch is tracking.  (And: `HEAD` means "the current branch, if on a branch", and omitting something in the `..` syntax means `HEAD`.)  Thus, `@{u}..` means "everything in HEAD that is not in its upstream":

```
[alias]
    top = log --oneline --graph --decorate @{u}..
```

Comment: Can you link some documentation? How do you know `@{u}` means upstream? And are there other `@{...}` options?

Comment: Yes, the places to look are in the documentation for [`git-rev-parse`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) and [`git-rev-list`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html).  There are a ton of funky syntax options, I use `rev^` all the time and `rev^{commit}` rarely, for instance, and still trying to start using `branch@{n}` more.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it:

```
[alias]
    top = "!git log --oneline --graph --decorate `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` ^origin/`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`"
```

Which turns alias into a shell command, which gives you an ability to nest commands.

Comment: This assumes that if you are on branch `foo` the upstream version is `origin/foo`, which is reasonable given the way the question is asked.  However, it's possible that the actual upstream, if any, is `origin/bar` or maybe `other-remote/foo` or even `other-remote/bar`.  Also I'd suggest using `git symbolic-ref --abbrev HEAD` in case `HEAD` is detached, although that brings in the question of how to fail gracefully :-)

Comment: @erikb85: er, yes, had `--abbrev-ref` stuck in my head or something; symbolic needs `--short` here..